# Get a specific List in Visual Studio 2012 Workflow (Sharepoint 2013)

Tags: workflow, visual-studio-2012

designing a visual studio workflow for SP 2013 I wonder how to get values of list items from another list than current list.
My workflow

- is not bound to a list
- has to access items of another list (let's call it 'customer')

I took a LookupSPList activity from Toolbox to the Sequence. Now, the Input is a ListId, hm. How to get the ListId of 'customer' list and how to retrieve list items from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Use an [Association or Initiation Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231590.aspx) and when creating the association you tell the workflow which lists it will be working with
2. Use the [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552(v=office.15).aspx) to query the list by title. You do this using the HttpSend activity.